# React Native data does not .push to firebase on first click

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, state

I'm trying to .push both the data from a TextInput field and created timestamp to Firebase Real-time Database. However, when the app is loaded, the first click on submit only submits the textInput and not the "timestamp"

This is a simple version of the file,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet, 
ImageBackground, TextInput, Alert, Picker, TouchableWithoutFeedback, 
Keyboard } from 'react-native';

import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet, 
ImageBackground, TextInput, Alert, Picker, TouchableWithoutFeedback, 
Keyboard } from 'react-native';

import { db } from '../config';


let date = new Date().getDate(); //Current Date

let month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; //Current Month

let year = new Date().getFullYear(); //Current Year

let hours = new Date().getHours(); //Current Hours

let min = new Date().getMinutes(); //Current Minutes

let sec = new Date().getSeconds(); //Current Seconds

let currentTimeAndDate


const updateDatabase = item => {
  db.ref('/Database/...').push({
    Amount: item,
    time: currentTimeAndDate
  });
};

export default class AddItem extends Component {  

constructor(props) {
  super (props);

  this.state = {
    pickerSelection: "default value!",
    date: " "

  };
}


handleSubmit = () => {    

  this.setState({
    //Setting the value of the date time
    date:
      date + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + 
':' + sec,

  });

  currentTimeAndDate = this.state.date

if (this.state.pickerSelection === "WHATEVER") {
      updateDatabase(this.state.textInputField);
      Alert.alert("database updated!");


//This is a short version of the View:

render() {
    return (

 <View>
  <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={TextInput.CheckTextInputIsEmptyOrNot}
    onPress={this.handleSubmit} 
   >
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Update</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
 </View>

 );
}
```

I already tried showing the currentTimeAndDate in Text upon clicking the TouchableHighLight. It doesn't show the first time clicked after loading the app, but it does the second.

in firebase the data is input like this the first time clicked:

```
EJDPvodisjpINJI_9
   amount: "(input number fx. 10)"
   time:   " "
```

The second time clicked:

```
Efvpspodvpoep_10
   amount: "(input number fx. "10")"
   time:   "(the local time of click fx. "8/5/2019 19:28:28")"
```

What can I do to make it send the local time the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

The setState is asynchronous which I figured must be why it was never sent to the database on first submit-button click.

I now made a function: SetTimeAndSubmit, which sets the time and the state: date, and first calls the handleSubmit method afterwards. This both the 'item' and the 'time' gets submitted to the database the first time! See code below:

```
//Method that sets current time and calls the handleSubmitfunction:

setTimeAndSubmit = () => {
let date = new Date().getDate(); //Current Date
let month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; //Current Month
let year = new Date().getFullYear(); //Current Year
let hours = new Date().getHours(); //Current Hours
let min = new Date().getMinutes(); //Current Minutes
let sec = new Date().getSeconds(); //Current Seconds

this.setState({
  //Setting the value of the date time
  date:
    date + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec,

  }, () => {
    //this will be executed when setState is done:
    this.handleSubmit();
});
}
```

I changed the update database call and function to Franks suggestion as well:
Update Database call:

```
if (this.state.pickerSelection === "WHATEVER") {
  updateDatabase(this.state.textInputField, this.state.date);
  Alert.alert("database updated!");
```

And the function is:

```
const updateDatabase = (item, time) => {
 db.ref('/Database/...').push({
  Amount: item,
  time: time
 });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about simply passing the `currentDateTime` into your `updateDatabase` call?

So you'd call it with:

```
updateDatabase(this.state.textInputField, currentTimeAndDate);
```

And then the function itself is:

```
const updateDatabase = (item, time) => {
  db.ref('/Database/...').push({
    Amount: item,
    time: time
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried that now, but the outcome is still the same. I found out however that if I press the submit button, even without any input and THEN inputs something in the field and presses again, then it gets sent to the database

Comment: So it seems like that this.state.date for longer to set and send to currentTimeAndDate than the first click. Do you know how to change og bypass that?

Comment: If you want the call to `setState()` to have propagated, you can either add a completion handler or implement `componentDidUpdate`. For an explanation of both, see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#setstate